# Iphone: Is it allowed to make the user register seperatly from app store?

Tags: iphone, registration

Ive tried to contact Apple about this, but they refuse to give me any answers. Do any of you know if it`s allowed to make the user register with a username,password and phone number before they can use the the application they have already downloaded from app store?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I've seen several applications that make you at least register with a username,  password, and email address. I believe it's safe to say that requiring this is OK with Apple.

Comment: +1 I agree. Typically, this is necessary when the iPhone app is linked with an online service. For example, Twitter. Twitter apps are not very useful until you provide login info.